# How to access fields of an object that contain '-' characters

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I have a JSON object that looks something like this:

```
"stats": {
    "task-stats": {
        "throughput": 0
    },
    "node-stats": {
        "from1": {
            "avg_exec_time_ns": 10504,
            "collected": 2108636,
            "emitted": 2108636
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting the object from a web service, and using [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse). I want to be able to declare those fields with dashes as a [TypeScript Interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html), but I'm not sure how to do that. Any ideas?

Comment: If the keys don't have double quotation marks, it ain't JSON.

Comment: In JavaScript code, that's called an object initializer, not "a JSON object". JSON is a serialization scheme, and really only applies as a term to the serialized (string) representation. In JavaScript it's just an object.

Comment: Why is your title "how to access"? Don't you mean "how to declare"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
interface Stats {
    "task-stats": {
        throughput: number
    }
    "node-stats": {
        from1: {
            avg_exec_time_ns: number,
            collected: number,
            emitted: number
        }
    }
}
```

How to use it:

```
var stats: Stats;
stats["task-stats"].throughput // OK
stats["node-stats"].from1 // OK
```